# updating a single image from a video using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create an image that will be updated each 10 frames from my webcam using FFMPEG.

I am using the following line:

```
/home/root/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -f image2 -update ../web/client/t.jpg
```

and I get the following error:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 18019.513484, bitrate: 36864 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 320x240, 36864 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

p.s.

I dont want to use this:

```
/home/root/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -f image2 ../web/client/t%d.jpg
```

because it will generate t1.jpg, t2.jpg ... and so on. I just want one output image that should be updated at the same time than the video of the webcam runs.

Answer (score 3):

`-update` takes a boolean as argument, so use

`ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f image2 -update 1 ../web/client/t.jpg`

(the mpeg1video and bitrate is irrelevant for saving to JPEG)